# UI of Process is not visible after Process.Start()

Tags: c#, wcf

I have made a WCF Service and it contains a method **string SaveVideoInformation()**

The purpose of this method is to run a process if it is not running.
Following is the code of that method.

```
 public string SaveVideoInformation(string ID, string videoName)
    {
        string Result = null;
        try
        {
            Result = Insert(ID, videoName);
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("AutoRunVideoWaterMarkingTook");
            if (pname.Length == 0)
            {
                Result += " | Trying to run Process";
                try
                {
                    Process process = Process.Start(@"~\Debug\AutoRunVideoWaterMarkingTook.exe");
                    Result += " | Process Ran Successfully";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Result += " | Exception While Running the process";
                    throw new Exception("Unable to start Process);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Result += "|Process Already Running";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Result = "Not Done," + ex.Message;
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

The problem I am facing is when i call this method from Windows Form Tool Application, it run successfully and i can see the UI.

but when i call this method from Windows Service, Process Starts but its UI is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely because your Windows Service is not in user interactive mode.

You have to enable this from the Services panel, as described in [this blog](https://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/): Check the `Allow service to interact with desktop` in the service properties `Log On` page.

Also read [Microsofts recommendations on user interactive services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I am using Windows 8. I made two changes. Made it interactive to desktop, made changes in registry and restart. After all that it is still not running on same desktop but prompt with Dialog box .Showing this message "A program running on computer is trying to display a message" After i click on View message. it takes me to another desktop where my tool is running

Comment: That might be a user issue. Which user does the service run under?

Comment: Since Vista, interactive services that can interact with the desktop, interact with a desktop in session 0. Not the desktop of a logged in user.